# POSIX ps commands' output format ends with =

Tags: linux, ps, posix

What does it mean by an equal sign that ps command ends with for its output format?

`ps -o gpid= 1111`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-o` option allows you to choose columns and set custom *column titles*. For example:

```
ps -o pid=PROCESS_ID,vsz=GOATS,cmd=PROGRAM
```

When all columns have empty titles, the column header is not shown at all. So using this syntax to specify just one column, with no title, is a common way to get *machine-readable* output out of `ps` (which would otherwise be somewhat unreliable to parse).